# Passing parameters to a website

Tags: parameters

Well, I'm a complete stranger to this topic; I don't even know the general name of this kind of operation, but I'm going to try to explain it. (it's probably something pretty basic)

I'm trying to write a auto-form-fill application. In order to have an interface planning to use GUI on VisualStudio.

It is simply some text boxes that are similar to web site's registration form and a register button to initialize the action.

The information that the user enters in those text boxes will be sent to similar text boxes on a predetermined website's registration page.
Then when I click the register button on my application, it will also click the register button on the webpage.

This is simply what I'm trying to do. How can I start? Which topics should I read up on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it homework? any great purpose behind this? any technology thought?

Comment: This is a very general question and you should really attempt something so you can show us some code first. But if you really don't have any ideas, start off by searching for *GET* and *POST* - they are the two basic ways of passing data to a webpage.

Comment: As I said I have no idea, I couldn't come up with a code.

Comment: By the way it's now a hw, just completed the advanced programming class this term, however professor didn't mention anything regarding that kind of connections. Thanks for advice, I'll try to search on that ;)

Comment: @user1449456 - In addition to Widor's suggestion, you should probably understand a little bit about HTTP in general. I thought [this](http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife) was a pretty good explanation (more targeted at a specific use of HTTP).

Answer (score 8):

A primary way to pass a parameter to a website is known as "Query String Parameter".

The notion is that a variable can be sent into a webpage through a url.

The format is appended after your webpage:

http...yoursite.com/yourpage.html?x='value'

So the QueryString is a variable x with the value of 'value'.

> ?x='value'

At this point a variable of x can be available to JavaScript.

Here is a [link](http://instruct.tri-c.edu/rrichmond/html/querystring.htm) to describe setup and usage. There are other on google that may be more specific to your environment.

Hope it helps.
All the best!
Nash